# Add time unit to Joda DateTime object

Tags: java, date, jodatime

Is there a better way to add a certain unit of time to a DateTime object?

I would like to do something similar to:

```
TimeUnit unit = TimeUnit.valueOf("days");
DateTime date = new DateTime().add(unit, 20);
```

This is my current implementation.

```
int number = 20;
MutableDateTime now = new MutableDateTime();
String timeUnit = getTimeUnit(); // returns "days", "months", "years"
if (timeUnit.equals("days"))
    now.addDays(number);
else if (timeUnit.equals("months"))
    now.addMonths(number);
else
    now.addYears(number);
return now.toDateTime();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in way to do it. Instead, you can create a `Map` of `String` names mapped to corresponding `DurationFieldType` objects. For example

```
static Map<String, DurationFieldType> durationFieldTypes = new HashMap<>();
static {
    durationFieldTypes.put("days", DurationFieldType.days());
    durationFieldTypes.put("months", DurationFieldType.months());
    ...
}
```

And then just query that `Map` for the appropriate object

```
MutableDateTime dateTime = new MutableDateTime();
String timeUnit = getTimeUnit(); // returns "days", "months", "years"
dateTime.add(durationFieldTypes.get(timeUnit), amount);
```

You will possibly need some fail safe for invalid `timeUnit` values.

Answer (score 4):

The answer of Sotirios Delimanolis is right. JodaTime has no enum-like concept because it was developed before the introduction of Java generics and enums in JDK5. In Java 8 you can also go this way or similar:

```
String name = "days"; // or months or years
ChronoUnit unit = ChronoUnit.valueOf(name.toUpperCase());
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(...);
ldt = ldt.plus(number, unit);
```

Or consider using `ZonedDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`. The new approach is much more elegant (yes JodaTime becomes old).